# Position absolute with margin bottom. Adding a spacer div is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with some elements in it. Then I have an absolute div below it (which I push to the top of the page). I want to add margin-bottom to the absolute div.

**However the requirements are :** I do not want to add margin-top to the "container-fluid" div. The absolute div should maintain absolute.

I tried adding a spacer div but that did not work ( It should work but it does not). All help is appreciated :)

### Demo:

```css
#container-test {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.spacer {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 -50px 0;
  /* margin: 20px 0 -50px 0; use this if you want #container to have a 'bottom padding', in this case of 20px */
  background: transparent;
  /* you'll need this if #container's parent element has a different background from #container itself */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./example.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Title 1 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="section-topleft">
          <h3>Title 1 - col-sm-4</h3>
        </div>
        <h3>Title 2 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <h3>Title 3 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='container-test'>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <p>This text should have a margin-bottom to push the other elements down.</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should look into what absolute positioning actually does. That element is essentially on another layer of the page, so margins on it don't affect the layer below. My guess is that you don't need absolute positioning. You should explain why you used it so we know what outcome you're after.

Comment: @isherwood I will tag bootstrap. Well I need absolute positioning. This is just a simple example but in the real project I have to use absolute positioning because the 3rd party program it's using is limited in what you can edit in the HTML :(

Comment: Well, you can't. Absolutely-positioned elements don't affect other elements in the page. You haven't said why you can't move the others with CSS, though.

Comment: @isherwood Aha okay, well I can't because in the real project I have to add margin-top to the bootstrap class: "col-md-3" for example. This will have effect on all the other elements with the "col-md-3" class. Maybe there is an way to add an class via CSS? (Or is this only possible with javascript Jquery?)

Comment: you can use bootstrap class for margin and padding acc. to the viewport. in bootstrap 3,4 we already have a inbuild margin classes acc. to viewport or screen. Like mt-sm-1 (marginTop for small screen)_, mb-md-2 (marginBottom for medium screen), ml-xs-3 (marginLeft for extra small), mr-lg-4 (marginRight for large screen), mx-xl-5 (margin left-right for extra large screen), my-1 (margin top-bottom for all screen). When you use these classes it will automatically adjust acc. to the viewport.

Comment: @bhartiparmar Hey, I think it's working or I found another solution. I am not sure anymore :P since it was a long time ago. Thanks for the help!